# How can use sendKey method in bat file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

first of all, I knew this question is duplicated but I'm new to bat file and I don't know how to develop this structure.
I want a bat file that works with windows task schedule at a specific time automatically.
I manually use this command in cmd

> php\php.exe  -f processmaker workspace-backup workflow

then I press enter in cmd to run this command

after that

I manually use this command in cmd

> SET PATH=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL server 5.6\bin

then I press enter in cmd again...

ok I want a solution to pressing "ENTER KEY" automatically between these commands.
Can you please help me?

Comment: Your problem does not need a send keys method at all.  It sounds like you are just entering commands at the command prompt which requires you to type enter to execute the command.  If you put those commands in a `.bat` file they will execute without any human intervention.  It is no different then creating a `PHP`, `PERL` or `PYTHON` script.

Comment: Also, it is generally not a good idea to set the `PATH` variable without considering the current value. There are many directories in the `PATH` variable that are needed to make the system work as expected. If it is needed for a single program invocation, it is usually better to specify the path in the command. "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL server 5.6\bin\the.exe"`

Answer (score 0):

If you edit a text file and name it, say mytask.bat
All the lines in it are executed as if in the command line, so try it, it should work.